# Написание чата android

Tags: android, websocket

Имеется задача - написать чат на android. Так же присутствует чат-сервер. Насколько я понял все нужно будет делать на сокетах. Но я не могу понять с чего начать :( Во-первых сложно найти адекватно работающую библиотеку или способ который даст ожидаемый результат. Надеялся что получится сделать все через `scarlet` от `Tinder` но что-то пошло не так, и зависимости не подключились адекватно. Появилось много проблем после установки требуемой версии java в `build.gradle`. Есть много библиотек и еще больше кустарных способов, но большинство из них отпадает из-за того что в адресах сервера используется протокол `http/https` а у меня используется `wss`. На текущий момент моя последняя попытка взята [отсюда](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) и тоже запрос не шлется:

```
val wsFactory = WebSocketFactory()
                .createSocket("wss://server/")
                .addHeader("token", context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
```

Либо я что-то не могу понять в принципах создания чата. До этого я работал с retrofit и возможно я жду обычного запрос-ответ поведения. Но судя по тому что я читаю, то здесь тоже приблизительно так все реализовано. Была так же такая попытка:

```
private fun instantiateWebSocket() {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url("wss://server/")
                .addHeader("token", context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                .build()


        Timber.i(request.toString())

        val socketListener = SocketListener(context!!)
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, socketListener)
        webSocket!!.send("0909")

    }

    class SocketListener(cont: Context) : WebSocketListener() {
        var context: Context = cont
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            Timber.i(response.toString())
            Runnable { Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Established!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            val jsonObject = JSONObject()
            try {
                jsonObject.put("message", text)
                jsonObject.put("byServer", true)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }

        init {
            this.context = cont
        }
    }
```

и тут запрос тоже не шлется. Что я не так делаю? Может у кого-то был опыт создания чата и есть рабочий способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный ответ пишу для таких же как и я - тех кто ничего не знает про сокеты и как писать чат. Я потратил немного времени на исследование и в итоге у меня получилось реализовать то что нужно. Для создания чата я использовал OkHttp. Для начала создадим клиент:

```
 val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build()
```

дальше формируем запрос:

```
val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(Constants.TEST_CHAT_URL)
                .build()
```

и наконец создаем сокет:

```
webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, object : WebSocketListener() {
            override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
                super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
                Timber.i("closing data: $code -> $reason")
            }

            override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
                super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason)
                webSocket.close(1000, null)
                Timber.i("Closing : $code / $reason")
            }

            override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
                super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
                Timber.i("Error: %s", t.localizedMessage)
            }

            override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
                Timber.i("Receiving : $text")

            }

            override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes)
                Timber.i("Receiving bytes : %s", bytes.hex())
            }

            override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
                super.onOpen(webSocket, response)
                Timber.i("on open")
            }
        })
```

После того как пообщались с человеком, нужно закрыть соединение:

```
webSocket.close(1000, null)
```

Для отправки сообщения нужно использовать функцию `send`:

```
webSocket.send("some_string")
```

Вот и все :) Оказалось не так сложно как казалось вначале. Возможно у кого-то будут замечания/предложения - выслушаю с удовольствием.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](https://juejin.cn/post/7170682805381234701) отличная статья по этой теме

Так же клиент:

```
private val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```

Запрос:

```
val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
```

И создаем сокет:

```
webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, object : WebSocketListener() {

        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            super.onOpen(webSocket, response)
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes)
        }

        override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
            super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason)
        }

        override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
            super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
        }

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
        }
    })
}
```

Ну и отправка сообщений + возможность закрытие сокет соединения

```
private fun sendMessage(message: String) {
    webSocket?.send(message)
}

private fun close(code: Int, reason: String) {
    webSocket?.close(code, reason)
}
```

Итогом послужит вот такой класс который можно разбросать в зависимости от вашей архитектуры

```
class WebSocketManager private constructor() {

    private val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    private var webSocket: WebSocket? = null

    companion object {
        val instance: WebSocketManager by lazy(mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.SYNCHRONIZED) { WebSocketManager() }
    }

    fun connect(url: String) {
        webSocket?.cancel()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, object : WebSocketListener() {

            override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
                super.onOpen(webSocket, response)
            }

            override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
            }

            override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes)
            }

            override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
                super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason)
            }

            override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
                super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
            }

            override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
                super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun sendMessage(message: String) {
        webSocket?.send(message)
    }

    private fun close(code: Int, reason: String) {
        webSocket?.close(code, reason)
    }
}
```

Еще советую почитать [доку](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4) по кодам закрытия соединения `onClosing`, если кратко то обычно хватает 1000 если сделали все что хотели или 1001 если просто ушли в другое место в приложении

Так же можно ознакомиться с MQTT, как говорит сам автор статьи:

> WebSocket проще и гибче, тогда как MQTT относительно сложен, но мощен,
> и вы можете выбирать в соответствии со своими сценариями
> использования.

Когда нибудь на хабр её перенесу с переводом

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)